# how to set image url time to genrate html to pdf in node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pdf

this is my html code i want to set my company logo int the invoice pdf which is genrate though html code this is my html code..

```
<header style="padding-left : 5%; padding-right : 5%;">
                    <div style="width : 100%">
                        <div class="box">
                            <img src="../../images/logo.png" style="height : 175px; width : 400px;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="box" style="float : right">
                            <div style="float : right">
                                <span>POWERD BY</span><br>
                                <img src="../../images/motocraft.png" style="height : 100px; width : 100px;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
```

i am using this node js library for genrate html to pdf

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
```

this is my pdf genrator code:-

```
pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./invoice.pdf', function(err, res) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' } 
        });
```

Comment: It's a bit u unclear what exactly you trying to do. Do you want to insert the html code you are showing into other html and then pass it to pdf.create?

Comment: i have a html form for invoice i want to add my company logo in to this form in img src tag but its, a html tag node js can not understand it this is the code   <img src="../../images/logo.png" style="height : 175px; width : 400px;"> my code generate pdf fine but it dos,t load image from my directory

Comment: i have my html code in a variable and the i generate pdf..

Comment: Then look into docs. There's a *base* property in options to tell the html-pdf where your static assets like images are.